# Understanding the Drools planner examples: where is the p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m state initialized?

Tags: drools, drools-planner

I am trying to understand the **N Queens** and **Cloud Balancer** examples of Drools. I delved into chapter 3 and 4 of the manual and the sources for the two examples.

I (mis)understand that

1. The problem has to begin from an unassigned or unoptimal state
2. So then, the problem facts and planning entities, which are POJOs, have to be instantiated
3. The solution class, such as CloudBalance or NQueens have to be aware of the problem facts and planning entities

---

**Question 1**: In the examples, where are the objects of the planning entity and problem fact classes **initialized**?

For example, when I load the cloud balancing, I see this:

```
2012 .. INFO  Loaded: data/cloudbalancing/unsolved/cb-0002comp-0006proc.xml
```

This means that a serialized format is converted to real objects and fed into a solution right?

---

**Question 2**: Where are the planning entities handled?

What is the meaning of that comment? How was that handled in the first place?

```
public Collection<? extends Object> getProblemFacts() {
    List<Object> facts = new ArrayList<Object>();
    facts.addAll(columnList);
    facts.addAll(rowList);
    // Do not add the planning entity's (queenList) because that will be done automatically
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: The planning instances where created in `NQueensGenerator`, `CurriculumCourseSolutionImporter`, ... and then serialized to an XML file with XStream. The load button just deserializes them from XML. Use the import button (not available in all examples) if you want to debug a `*SolutionImporter`.

Q2: It means that getProblemFacts() should not do facts.addAll(queenList).
Planner does that automatically due to this annotation:

```
@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
public List<Queen> getQueenList() {
    return queenList;
}
```

Comment: Right on! I was (biased) expecting some ORM-ish code for XStream. And I wish I paid more attention to what the annotators do. And the part they (annotators), entities in SolverConfig.xml and solution class play in the Grand Scheme of things. I will give you more feedback in future.

Comment: @geoffrey-de-smet, i also trying to understand **NQueens** (drools-planner 5.3.0 Final ) example, but it is a little beat difficult, because of **XStream** ... do you have examples without XStream, GUI ...

Comment: @Nurian Currently not, but I guess I need a hello world 8 queens main.